# jsf application in jboss web server

Tags: jsf

I try to run jsf application in myeclipse using jboss web server and following error while running jboss server.

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/3aprwebdemo.war/ state=Not Installed mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/3aprwebdemo.war/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:337)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:297)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:269)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:230)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '3aprwebdemo' is not a valid value for 'NCName'. @ vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/3aprwebdemo.war/WEB-INF/web.xml[5,20]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:203)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.JBossXBDeployerHelper.parse(JBossXBDeployerHelper.java:199)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.JBossXBDeployerHelper.parse(JBossXBDeployerHelper.java:170)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:132)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:118)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:256)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:323)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '3aprwebdemo' is not a valid value for 'NCName'. @ vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/3aprwebdemo.war/WEB-INF/web.xml[5,20]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser$MetaDataErrorHandler.error(SaxJBossXBParser.java:426)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:199)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Please do not reuse an old question for a new question. Please post each new and independent question as a new question by pressing the `Ask Question` button. Otherwise the posted answers don't make any sense anymore. Further, in your new question please also pay attention to the code formatting. You can do it by simply selecting the piece of text and pressing the `010101` button or the `Ctrl+K` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> '3aprwebdemo' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
> ```

It may not start with a digit. Only with a letter or an underscore.